# How to redirect login page after completing form in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, redirect

I have a php form at [Sell Your Car](https://www.carsangrah.com/sell-my-used-car/%22Sell%20Your%20Car%22). This required login, so it is redirected to [Login](https://www.carsangrah.com/login/). Then sell page form opens. I want user to be able to fill sell page form first and then redirected to login page.

Answer (score 0):

On clicking login button you can redirect it.Please try this

```
<input type="submit" name="loginbutton" value="Login">

    if (isset($_POST['loginbutton']))
        {   
        ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "https://www.carsangrah.com/login/";
    </script>      
        <?php
        }
```

Comment: Form in sell page requires user id which is available after login. How will I get user id if login page comes after completing form in sell page?